# Windows Store App - how to get watermark in Search Charm textbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've implemented the Search Contract in my Windows 8 App.

However, when the user brings up the search charm from within the App, the search box is initially blank.   I notice that other Apps have a default 'watermark' within the box, such as the Bing Maps app:

[image]

How can I reproduce this behaviour and add my own watermark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it's not documented on the [main Quickstart page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868180%28v=win.10%29.aspx#test_your_search_contract_integration) or [search guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465233.aspx), but you do it like this:

```
    protected override async void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        SearchPane sp = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView();
        sp.PlaceholderText = "Enter the name of a town or city";
    }
```

I suggest placing it into the OnWindowCreated(...) method in App.xaml.cs